# AsyncTask in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When i make my app run it doesn't go into onPostExecute() but when i debug it it works ,what can i do??I tried the thread.sleep() method but it doesn't help!!

Please what can i do in order for my `AsyncTask` to work while running

```
try {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                tempBook = backend.returnBook(book.getName(), book.getAuthor(), book.getEdition());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            book_provider.setId_Book(tempBook.getId_Book());
        }
    }.execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

book_provider.setId_Provider(provider.getId_Provider());
book_provider.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()));
book_provider.setAmount_In_Stock(Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()));

try {
    backend.addBook_Provider(book_provider);
} catch (Exception e) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(Add_Book.this);
    builder1.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    builder1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp);
    builder1.setTitle("WARNING!");
    builder1.setCancelable(true);
    builder1.setPositiveButton("Update this book",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Add_Book.this, details_book_provider.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("book", book);
                    intent1.putExtra("provider", provider);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the thread.sleep? And you should return tempBook in doInBackground instead of null

Comment: Don't ever sleep() the main thread

Comment: but the doInBackground is a void method??

Comment: Are all permissions set? Sometimes there are different behaviours in debug and release builds.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask allows you to specify the return types of the objects which you want to use for the different methods.  The declaration is AsyncTask

For this example I'm going to assume that `tempBook` is an instance of the class `Book`.  You would need to do something like:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Book>() {

    @Override
    protected Book doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            return backend.returnBook(
                book.getName(), 
                book.getAuthor(), 
                book.getEdition()
            );

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Book result) {

        book_provider.setId_Book(result.getId_Book());
    }

}.execute();
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't get to the root of the OP's problem.  It looks like they are using a member variable of the Activity instead of a return value, which would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should remove sleep in main thread as you've been told.
Also I'll recommend to move the code

```
book_provider.setId_Provider(provider.getId_Provider());
book_provider.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()));
book_provider.setAmount_In_Stock(Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()));
```

to the onPostExecute
You should understand that it's Async code and this code is executed before the command

```
 book_provider.setId_Book(tempBook.getId_Book());
```